# Inserting a row with a negative offset is crashing Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I want to add a page break and insert a blank row above all of the cells that read "Total Hours:". The page break does not give me a problem, and when I try to insert a row with a positive offset (such as (1,0)), the row is successfully created, albeit further down than I want it. Once I set the negative (-1,0) and run the macro, excel crashes and I'm forced to close the program. Any idea of what's going on, and what I can do to get my row?

I've also tried offset (0,0), which also crashed the program.

```
Sub InsertPBs()

Dim rngMyRange As Range, rngCell As Range

Set rngMyRange = Range("H7:H3000")

For Each rngCell In rngMyRange

    If rngCell.Value = "Total Hours:" Then

        ''successfully creates my page breaks''
        ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.HPageBreaks.Add Before:=rngCell.Offset(0, 0)

        ''crashes excel instead of creating a row''
        rngCell.Offset(-1, 0).EntireRow.Insert
    End If

Next
End

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tired without the Offset; just using rngCell.EntireRow.Insert xlShiftDown?

Comment: Sound like an infinite loop.  I suspect after the insert the cell with "Total Hours:" is now one row lower, and will be found again on the next iteration,  and so on forever.  Change the loop to `For idx = rngMyRange.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1` and add `Set rngCell = rngMyRange.Cells(idx, 1)`

Comment: Note that `Offset(0, 0)` is completely useless and can be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Like Chris said in the comment above, the problem you are having is an infinite loop. You need to step up from the bottom of your range in order to avoid having `Total Hours:` found over and over again forever. Try This:

```
Sub InsertPBs()

    Dim rngMyRange As Range, rngCell As Range

    Set rngMyRange = Range("H7:H3000")

    Dim i As Long

    For i = rngMyRange.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
    Set rngCell = rngMyRange.Cells(i, 1)
        If rngCell.Value = "Total Hours:" Then
            ''successfully creates my page breaks''
            ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.HPageBreaks.Add Before:=rngCell.Offset(0, 0)
            ''crashes excel instead of creating a row''
            rngCell.EntireRow.Insert xlShiftDown
        End If

    Next
    End

End Sub
```